# Power Query - How to extract values in the list of the list?

Tags: powerquery

First of all, thank you so much for your interest in my question and for coming in to read the contents.

I'm a college student, and now I have some problems.

I want to import data from API related to buildings. (I'm working on the project about the sunlight simulator.)

However, in the power query, there are some values whose type is MultiPolygon, and I have a problem when I extract their values.

There are lists in the list, and the coordinate values of MutiPolygon are present in it, so there is no way to load multiple values into a single row.

I've been searching for information about it for about two weeks, but I can't find it because of the limitations of my knowledge.

(And I also found information about "combine". My problem is about the list in the list, not about representing multiple values in the same row.)

So I would appreciate it if you can give me some advice. Anything is ok.

Below is an example of the data I have.

[image]

This is MultiPolygon data.

[image]

In the list, there is the list.

[image]

And also, in the list, there is the list.

[image]

And in the list, there are lists. In these lists, there are latitude & longitude values.

Thank you for reading it, and have a nice day.

Comment: Also, I'm Korean, and it's too late now, so I think I can get up tomorrow morning and give you additional comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain this is what you're asking for, but what the heck. Here goes anyway.

If you are asking for a way to surface the information that is nested in your third-level lists and bring it to the top level as single concatenated text entries for each row, here's one way.

To access the information in the first level's list, you just need `#"Previous Step"[ListColumnName]{index}`

Assuming that only one list exists within each of the first level lists, and only one list exists within each of the second level lists, you could use `#"Previous Step"[ListColumnName]{index}{0}{0}` to drill through the second and into the third. (The zeroes are also index references.)

Knowing this, you could use something like `Text.Combine(List.Transform(#"Previous Step"[Coordinates]{[Index]}{0}{0}, each Text.From(_ & "; ")))` to get the coordinates from the third level list and concatenate them as a single text entry with a semicolon between them.

You would have to create an index column before you could do this, because you need to use it for the index referencing.

Here's some sample M code you can paste as a query to see how this works:

```
let
Source = Table.FromRecords({
[Coordinates = {{{"28.09, 0.62", "28.82, -1.63", "30, 2.01", "31.91, 0.62", "31.18, -1.63"}}}],
[Coordinates = {{{"28.09, 0.52", "28.82, -1.64", "30, 2.00", "31.91, 0.52", "31.18, -1.64"}}}],
[Coordinates = {{{"28.09, 0.42", "28.82, -1.65", "30, 1.99", "31.91, 0.42", "31.18, -1.65"}}}],
[Coordinates = {{{"28.09, 0.32", "28.82, -1.66", "30, 1.98", "31.91, 0.32", "31.18, -1.66"}}}],
[Coordinates = {{{"28.09, 0.22", "28.82, -1.67", "30, 1.97", "31.91, 0.22", "31.18, -1.67"}}}],
[Coordinates = {{{"28.09, 0.12", "28.82, -1.68", "30, 1.96", "31.91, 0.12", "31.18, -1.68"}}}],
[Coordinates = {{{"28.09, 0.02", "28.82, -1.69", "30, 1.95", "31.91, 0.02", "31.18, -1.69"}}}],
[Coordinates = {{{"28.09, 0.72", "28.82, -1.62", "30, 2.02", "31.91, 0.72", "31.18, -1.62"}}}]
}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom.1", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(#"Added Index"[Coordinates]{[Index]}{0}{0}, each Text.From(_ & "; "))))
in
#"Added Custom1"
```

This code creates a table with lists of coordinates like this list below for each of seven top level table rows; but it nests those list three levels down as you described is the case with your setup. Then it ultimately extracts each row's lists' information into a new column like the second table shows below.

[image]

[image]

*If my assumption about there only being one list within each of the first level lists and only one list within each of the second level lists is not correct, then this approach will not work and your task will be much more involved.*

Comment: I think my question is difficult to understand... (I'm not good at English.. sorry for that) However, your answer is all I want. I deeply appreciate your efforts to answer my question.